# Change mat-select default value

Tags: angular-material

I can't change the default value or my mat-select item even if i set value property in the proper way.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.vehicles$ = this.vehicleService.getVehicles();
if (this.fuelId > 0) {
  this.editClicked();
  this.fuelService.getFuel(this.fuelId).subscribe(data => (
      ......
      this.vehicleList.patchValue(data.vehicle),
      console.log(this.vehicleList.value),
      ......
    ));
}
```

This is the log output:

```
fuel-add-edit.component.ts:55 {id: 20, plate: "random1", fuels: Array(0), journeys: Array(0), maintenances: Array(0)}
```

and this is my mat-select

```
<mat-form-field class="float-left w-75">
  <mat-label>Scegli Automezzo</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="vehicleList" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles$ | async" [value]="vehicle">
      {{ vehicle.plate }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

I would like to have the proper vehicle already selected when editing an item instead of "Scegli automezzo"

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60050439/angular-material-select-default-value-reactive-forms/60050590#60050590
You need to use [compareWith] if the value is an object.

Comment: You were correct! Never thought about the issue that way! Thanks a lot. If you make it as asnwer i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must pass in a `[compareWith]` function if the value is an object. See the answer in [Angular Material Select - Default Value - Reactive Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60050439/angular-material-select-default-value-reactive-forms/60050590#60050590) for a full explanation of the problem.